# Passing print pattern as a variable to awk

Tags: shell, awk, ksh

I am trying to use `awk` to print variables from various columns in a line delimited by  `,` .The columns and pattern which I want to print is stored in another variable `b`.
The pattern `a` and print patter `b` are given below:

```
a='15986327,415532694,850257614,875121642,20140819'
b='$1","$2","$4'
```

I am trying to get the output as below.

```
15986327,415532694,875121642
```

I am trying to pass the pattern `b` to awk using `-v` switch but not sure how to use that with `print` inside `awk`. Tried below commands but this is not the output I was trying to get to.

```
echo $a |awk -v ba="${b}" -F"," '{print ba}'
$1","$2","$4

echo $a |awk -v ba="${b}" -F"," '{print $ba}'
15986327,415532694,850257614,875121642,20140819
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to use variable `ba`, try:

```
$ echo $a | awk -F',' '{print '"$b"'}'
15986327,415532694,875121642
```

With this, `$b` is expanded by the shell, not by `awk`. And the rest of `awk` statement is not affect, because they're enclosed in single quote.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` variables are just used for their values, like variables in most languages - they aren't re-parsed for expressions. You can do what you want with this:

```
a='15986327,415532694,850257614,875121642,20140819'
echo $a | awk -F, -v OFS=, '{print $1, $2, $4}'
```

(setting `OFS` so you get commas in the output). If having `b` as a variable is required, you can use:

```
b='$1, $2, $4'
echo $a | awk -F, -v OFS=, "{print $b}"
```

instead, which substitutes `b` in as part of the `awk` expression.

---

All of that said, you don't need `awk` for this. This is really a job for [`cut`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cut.html):

```
echo "$a" | cut -d, -f1,2,4
```

That selects fields 1, 2, and 4, using `,` as a field delimiter, with no complex double parsing of code. This is exactly what `cut` is made for.